# Triggering a script on another object when Clicking and Dragging in Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

I am doing a 2D project where I've added a sprite as a button to shoot.  This button works fine.  The script attached is:  (I added a box collider to the sprite)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public shootTest _shooterScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void LoadScript()
    {
        _shooterScript.ShootRock();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2();
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Collider2D hitCollider = new Collider2D();
            hitCollider = this.collider2D;
        hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition);

            Debug.Log("mouse pos "+mousePosition.x+" y "+mousePosition.y+" ");    


            if(hitCollider){
                LoadScript();
                Debug.Log("Hit "+hitCollider.transform.name+" x"+hitCollider.transform.position.x+" y "+hitCollider.transform.position.y);    
            }
    }
}}
```

Then I added a crosshair to be able to calculate a direction to aim.  Here is the script to click and drag the object. Circle Colider 2D on this object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class Aim : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);

        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));

    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {

        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);

        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint)+offset;
        this.transform.position = curPosition;

    }

}
```

When I add this aiming script and click on the crosshair to drag it, the shoot script goes off.

I'm very new to unity so I'm assuming it is something simple.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the update function in the click script to

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2();
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);


        if(this.collider2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition)){
            LoadScript();

        }
}
```

So it only triggers when that specific object is clicked.  Maybe there is a cleaner way, but this worked.